# change items to display in ox carousel with vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, buefy

[image]

Hi, I am using Buefy's "carousel" component with Vue.js. In laptop resolution I have to show 3 elements. But on the phone I want an article to be shown. I made a function that depends on the resolution the property of the carousel is changed "elements to show" from 3 to 1. But the bad thing that that property is loaded when the page starts not when the screen changes.

Do you have any advice on how to do it? I don't want to have to reload the page to make it happen. But at least reload the component

```
<b-carousel-list v-model="test" :data="items" :items-to-show="valor" :items-to-list="3" icon-size="is-large">
    <template slot="item" slot-scope="props">
        <div class="card redondo">
            <div class="card-image">
                <figure class="image is-5by4">
                     <a @click="info(props.index)"><img :src="props.list.image" class="imagen-redondo"></a>
                </figure>

methods: {
        info(value) {
            this.test = value

        },
        cambiar() {

            return this.test = 0;
        },
        itemMostrar() {
            if ($(window).width() < 720) {
                return this.valor = 1;
            } else {

                return this.valor = 3;
            }
        },
  
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a computed instead of a method. Your method will not re-run except you call it. A computed will update by itself